# Unable to addProjection to relation field in envers query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

Let say we have an entity:

```
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
public class MyEntity  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String Name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentEntityId")
    private MyEntity parentEntity;
}
```

I try to make envers returns entity revisions info on entity field that represents relation. I use `addProjection` to create my own representation of data. The problem is that each time I use with `addProjection` a name of a field that represents relation I've got an error (there is no error if I use oridinary column).

I build an audit query:

```
AuditQuery auditQuery = reader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(MyEntity.class, false, true);

    auditQuery.addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionNumber());
    auditQuery.addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionType());        
    auditQuery.addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp"));
    auditQuery.addProjection(AuditEntity.id());
    auditQuery.addProjection(new AuditProperty<>(
                        new EntityPropertyName("parentEntity")));
    auditQuery.addProjection(new AuditProperty<>(
        new ModifiedFlagPropertyName(
            new EntityPropertyName("parentEntity"))));
```

And the error is:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: parentEntity of: edu.sample.domain.entity.MyEntity_AUD
```

I also tried to: `new EntityPropertyName("parentEntityId")` - the result is:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: parentEntityId of: edu.sample.domain.entity.MyEntity_AUD
```

**EDIT**:
I missed one statement in Audit query. The projection should include parentEntity field value, not only modified flag: 
`auditQuery.addProjection(new AuditProperty<>(
                            new EntityPropertyName("parentEntity")));`

I need the value of the field and the information if it was modified. That's why I use `withModifiedFlag = true`

The problem is that the schema of MyEntity_AUD  table (autogenerated) contains field `parentEntityId`. The modified flag field name is `parentEntity_MOD`. The error manifests after adding to the query following projection:

- `addProjection(new AuditProperty<>(
                          new EntityPropertyName("parentEntity")));`

or

- `addProjection(new AuditProperty<>(
                          new EntityPropertyName("parentEntityId")));`

The modification flag is returned properly without error. As well as the values of ordinary fields.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to use a projection rather than using the returned `Object[]` when specifying `selectOnlyEntities=false`?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use projections here you can do this using the `selectEntity` option.  The syntax you're looking for here is as follows:

```
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery()
  .forRevisionsOfEntity( MyEntity.class, false, true );

query.addProjection( AuditEntity.revisionNumber() );
query.addProjection( AuditEntity.revisionType() );
query.addProjection( AuditEntity.revisionProperty( "timestamp" ) );
query.addProjection( AuditEntity.selectEntity( false ) );
```

You should be able to now use that particular entry in the returned object array to access any associations or attributes at that revision.  But be mindful this isn't very different from using the following syntax:

```
List results = reader.createQuery()
  .forRevisionsOfEntity( MyEntity.class, false, true )
  .getResultList();

for ( Object row : results ) {
  final Object[] array = (Object[]) row;
  final MyEntity entity = (MyEntity) array[0];
  final Object revisionEntity = array[1];
  final RevisionType revisionType = (RevisionType) array[2];
}
```

The only caveat here is that the `revisionEntity` could be any number of implementations that Envers exposes or your own custom implementation depending on how you've configured your environment.  You'd have to check to see which is being used and cast accordingly.

Both are synonymous and yield the same results.

**The only real difference is that the former returns the entity as a `Map<String,Object>` where-as the latter returns the actual hydrated entity instance.**

Comment: I cannot find `AuditEntity.selectEntity` method in [envers docs](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/api-new/org/hibernate/envers/query/AuditEntity.html). The root of  `addProjection ` usage lays in the need for getting info about field modification (I use `withModifiedFlag=true`). Can I get this info some other way, without `addProjection`?

Comment: Mayby I should create: `@Entity class MyEntity_AUD{ ...}` ?

Comment: If you are not using Hibernate 5.2.x you won't see that method.  It was added as a part of the new association traversal support for Envers.  Otherwise, you'll have to resort to the latter solution I posted for earlier releases.  As to creating the entity, don't do that.  You'll break the integration with Envers if you clash names like that.

Comment: but how can I obtain an info about a vaule together with a modification flag? Up to the problem with relation representation field I've done projection  `auditQuery.addProjection(new AuditProperty<>(
                            new EntityPropertyName("name")));` `auditQuery.addProjection(new AuditProperty<>(
        new ModifiedFlagPropertyName(
            new EntityPropertyName("name"))));`. And it was fine. The problem is with relations. I cannot do a projection on such a field.

Comment: That is because relation support as a part of the query API itself is something that is relatively new and still being added/adjusted.  As I have already mentioned, you either need to upgrade to 5.2+ if you want to use the projection API or use the latter approach mentioned if you want to stay on prior release to 5.2.